# add button and get column selected on p-datatable

Tags: user-interface, angular5, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a p-datatable as follows

```
<p-dataTable [(value)]="test.TestDetails" [paginator]="true" [rows]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[3,6,9]">
<p-column header="Test1" field="test1"></p-column>
<p-column header="Test2" field="test2"></p-column>
<p-column header="Test3" field="test3"></p-column>
<p-column header="Test4" field="test4" ></p-column>

<p-column  >
  <ng-template let-TestDetails="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <button  type="button" class="ui-button-reset-transparent" pButton (click)="SelectTest()"  ></button>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>

</p-dataTable>
```

If I click on the button the row should get selected/highlighted automatically. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selection directives and add `selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedRow"` to your `p-dataTable`.

`selectedRow` will contain the data of the row you want to be selected. Send the `rowIndex` to your `SelectTest` method so that you'll know which item of `test.TestDetails` you have to assign to `selectedRow` :

```
SelectTest(rowIndex) {
  this.selectedRow = this.test.TestDetails[rowIndex];
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lOLIUeaWPIThG7FRvKDZ?p=preview)